# Is it possible for pyspark to read from a table in S3, work the data and then save on the same folder?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

what I want to do is to consolidate some data within a folder on s3 and save the data (consolidated) on the same directory. Is it possible ?

I already tried:

```
DF1.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy("month").save("s3://path/db/table/")
```

But it seems to clear the directory before it can be read and consolidated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are various different modes you can use to save the data like append : to append the data, overwrite : to overwrite the data and so on.

You can find more informaton on modes here for pyspark :

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save

However, If above infomration is not useful then if you can also elaborate a bit more what do you mean by "consolidated" data with some example may help.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: Sorry, I did not really explain myself. What I mean for consolidated is:
Table A (s3://path/A/)
then I union Table A with Table B (streamed data) and work the data to do a rownum and get the last row of each ID, then I'd like to save the results on s3://path/A/ (table A folder) so I can repeat the same steps everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you'll have to cache the source dataframe before overwriting, otherwise the lazy loading of data from parquet will cause issues when writing to the same location.

A simple example

```scala
val sourceFile = "/tmp/testoverwrite/A"

val init = List(("A", 1), ("B", 1), ("C", 1)).toDF("X", "count")
init.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(sourceFile)

val rand = Random

(0 to 3).foreach{_ =>
    val A = spark.read.parquet(sourceFile).cache()
    val _ = A.count() // Trigger cache

    val B = (0 to 4).map(_ =>((rand.nextInt(10) + 65).toChar.toString, 1)).toDF("X", "count")
    A.union(B).groupBy('X).agg(sum('count).as("count"))
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(sourceFile)

    A.unpersist(true)
}

val A = spark.read.parquet(sourceFile).show()
```